# How to implement PM2 clustering with WebSockets, Nodejs

Tags: node.js, websocket, pm2

I am writing real time connection web server with WebSocket(ws) library in Node js(Express).so when I am running server on pm2 cluster mode than websocket not working properly.Is there any way to make share data between pm2 clusters with websocket.

Comment: What kind of data needs to be shared between the nodes? I am not sure what you are asking. Are you asking to share the data through websockets provided by each node?

Comment: yes.when i run my server on cluster mode than websocket communication not working properly.it may send message to another user or may be not.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can switch the library to [socket.io](https://socket.io/) they already solve this issue by using redis adapter for socket.io [Socket.IO Redis](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis)

> By running socket.io with the socket.io-redis adapter you can run multiple socket.io instances in different processes or servers that can all broadcast and emit events to and from each other.

Comment: yes socket.io works on cluster mode .but i have used websocket due to some performance issue.is there any solution related to same.

Comment: @vipinsharma Because of that, I don't feel like this really answers the question. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, that's kind of the point of cluster mode. It wouldn't be able to keep the connection alive across multiple "nodes" running processes. Straight from the PM2 docs:

*Be sure your application is stateless meaning that no local data is stored in the process, for example sessions/websocket connections, session-memory and related. Use Redis, Mongo or other databases to share states between processes.*

If you could pull out your websocket into its own instance and avoid side effects from a pm2 cluster--that's probably the most performant, although maybe not feasible in your set up. Best of luck!